# How can I display item in ToDo List

Tags: reactjs

How to make todo list in react.I am following some  tutorial how to work with react. This code is using input for adding item to list . How can I add item over h3 element instead input element?
This code is working perfect , I am looking for another way . Thank you
Here is full code .

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid'

const Header = () => {
 

const [input, setInput] = useState('')
const [todos, setTodos ] = useState([])

const onInput = (e) => {
  setInput(e.target.value)
  console.log(input)
}

const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault()
  setTodos([...todos, {id: uuidV4(), title:input, completed:false}])
  setInput('')
} 

  return (
    <section className='header'>
      <h1>ToDo List</h1>

      <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
          <input 
                type="text"
                placeholder='Add Item'
                className='input'
                value={input}
                required
                onChange={onInput} />

          <button 
                className='btn'
                type='submit' > Add </button>      
      </form>
      <br /><br />
       <ul>
         {todos.map((todo) => (      
         
           <li className='todo-list'>  // here is output 
                                       // <h3> { ? } </h3>  it should go todo.title
                                       // can you show me how, pls ? 
              <input 
                 type="text"
                 value={todo.title}
                 className='list'
                 onChange={(e)=>e.preventDefault()} /> 
                

           </li>
         ))}
       </ul>

    </section>
  )
  
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the title of the todo from the todo object passed to .map() function.

```
<h3>{todo.title}</h3>
```

```js
// Get a hook function
const {useState} = React;

const Header = () => {
  const [input, setInput] = useState("");
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const onInput = (e) => {
    setInput(e.target.value);
    //console.log(input);
  };

  const onFormSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setTodos([...todos, { id: Math.random(), title: input, completed: false }]);
    setInput("");
  };

  return (
    <section className="header">
      <h1>ToDo List</h1>

      <form onSubmit={onFormSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Add Item"
          className="input"
          value={input}
          required
          onChange={onInput}
        />

        <button className="btn" type="submit">
          {" "}
          Add{" "}
        </button>
      </form>
      <br />
      <br />
      <ul>
        {todos.map((todo) => (
          <li className="todo-list">
            <h3> {todo.title} </h3>

            <input
              type="text"
              value={todo.title}
              className="list"
              onChange={(e) => e.preventDefault()}
            />
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </section>
  );
};

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <Header />,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you , it is working , but I dont need set-up  id ?

Comment: you do and also set key for your todos ```<li key={todo.id} ...```

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys

Comment: I am looking to code , for this output and it does not make sence to me , put h3 element to li element. It should be only  {todo.title}